# Firefox iframe exceeding width

Tags: html, google-chrome, firefox, iframe

I have a webform (asp.net page) that has an iframe that is created using javascript.

In Chrome (Version 64.0.3282.140) it appears correctly with the HTML as shown below:

```html
<div id="mydiv" class="row col-sm-12" style="width: 100%; border-width: 1px; border-style: solid; border-color: rgb(95, 65, 147);">
   <div style="background-color:#5f4193 !important; color:white;  height:32px;">
      <a id="kev_cphContent_lbCloseDitto" href="javascript:__doPostBack('kev$cphContent$lbCloseMyPage','')" style="font-size:23px; color:white; text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff; padding-right:4px; text-decoration:none; cursor:pointer; float:right;">×</a>
   </div>
   <iframe src="http://page.mysite.org/Default.aspx" id="myframe" frameborder="0" style="width: 100%; height: 600px;"></iframe>
</div>
```

With Firefox Quantum (version 58.0.1), the iframe sets itself to width: 104%

```html
<div id="mydiv" class="row col-sm-12" style="width: 100%; border-width: 1px; border-style: solid; border-color: rgb(95, 65, 147);">
   <div style="background-color:#5f4193 !important; color:white;  height:32px;">
      <a id="kev_cphContent_lbCloseDitto" href="javascript:__doPostBack('kev$cphContent$lbCloseMyPage','')" style="font-size:23px; color:white; text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff; padding-right:4px; text-decoration:none; cursor:pointer; float:right;">×</a>
   </div>
   <iframe src="http://page.mysite.org/Default.aspx" id="myframe" style="width: 104%; height: 604px;" frameborder="0"></iframe>
</div>
```

Both are created from the same piece of code:

```js
        function setIframe(element, location) {
            url = 'http://page.mywebsite.org/Default.aspx?' + location;
            $('<iframe>', {
                src: url,
                id: 'dittoframe',
                width: '100%',
                height: '600px',
                frameborder: 0,
            }).appendTo('#kev');
            $("#main_data").hide();
            $("#kev").show();
        }
```

Can anyone clue me into how I can force Firefox to keep it at 100%?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Bit of a simple one when you look back at it.

Added the following code right after create the iframe

```js
function setIframe(element, location) {
            url = 'http://page.mywebsite.org/Default.aspx?' + location;
            $('<iframe>', {
                src: url,
                id: 'dittoframe',
                width: '100%',
                height: '600px',
                frameborder: 0,
            }).appendTo('#kev');
            $("#main_data").hide();
            $("#kev").show();
            $("#myframe").css("width", "100%"); // <- set the width to 100% immediately
        }
```

This immediately resizes the iframe even though it likely isn't loaded yet, and it appears as expected in Firefox.